# "Compile Error Syntax error" calling function

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2008, vb6

I want to call a DLL in VB6 and I have working code in Visual Studio 2008 (example program).

==== This is the Visual Studio 2008 Code ====

```
Declare Function InitStp Lib "stp.dll" () As Integer
Declare Function RunMotor1 Lib "stp.dll" (ByVal steps As Integer, ByVal interval As Integer, ByVal direction As Integer, ByVal outputs As Integer) As Boolean

Private Sub Command1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Stop1.Click
  InitStp ()
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Stop1.Click
  RunMotor1 (200, 50, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

==== This is the VB6 Code ====

```
Private Declare Function InitStp Lib "stp.dll" () As Integer
Private Declare Function RunMotor1 Lib "stp.dll" (ByVal steps As Integer, ByVal interval As Integer, ByVal direction As Integer, ByVal outputs As Integer) As Boolean

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  InitStp ()
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  RunMotor1 (200, 50, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

When I try to run the code for InitStp() I get the "Compile Error Syntax error" (the code InitStp() is already red in de VB6 indicating that there is an error). This is the same for "RunMotor1 (200, 50, 0, 0)".

It looks that my conversion is not OK...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever else may be going on, in VB6 you should not use parentheses around arguments to a `Sub` unless you also use the `Call` keyword. This applies to `Function`s invoked as `Sub`s as well In other words:

```
 RunMotor1 200, 50, 0, 0
```

-- or --

```
 Call RunMotor1 (200, 50, 0, 0)
```

But never

```
 RunMotor1 (200, 50, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

A VB.Net `Integer` is 32 bits but a VB6 `Integer` is 16 bits, in VB6 `Long` is the 32 bit type so use that in your declares.

```
InitStp ()
```

Is invalid syntax, remove the parentheses and have `InitStp` on its own - but this ignores the return value with is often not a good idea so instead:

```
Dim result as Long
result = InitStp()
```

Comment: Thanks It works!

The Code now

`Private Declare Function InitStp Lib "stp.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Function RunMotor1 Lib "stp.dll" (ByVal steps As Long, ByVal interval As Long, ByVal direction As Long, ByVal outputs As Long) As Boolean

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Call InitStp
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Call RunMotor1(200, 50, 0, 0)
End Sub`